# Want to move UIAlert at the top of view

Tags: ios, swift, frame, uialertcontroller

First time when user taps on Camera icon, alert is displayed 'App would like to access your camera'. I want this Alert at top. Any Hint?

Comment: no is not possible ,

Comment: show your screenshot the error which you are facing

Comment: @Kiran -- the questioner ased to handle default apple provided the alert , it is possible to change

Comment: @Kiran -I am not facing any error. Just want to move position of an alert.

Comment: move position of alert where? you mean updating its frame like below or up?

Comment: @Kiran - yes or can I show custom alert for that?

Comment: No that is not feasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make custom AlertView,

Use this reference this may help you.

> http://iosdevtricks.blogspot.in/2013/04/creating-custom-alert-view-for-iphone.html

or

> http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-uialertview-custom-graphics--mobile-8886

and many more.

Comment: No you have to create custom alertview. Only that is the solution.

Comment: It look like default alertview as in ios

Comment: @Avinash651 -- the questioner ased to handle default apple provided the alert , it is possible to change

Comment: can we make custom alert for camera permission first time? I think it is default alert? can we replace it with custom?

Comment: According to my knowledge, may be its not. Default alert appear.

Answer (score 1):

**No is not possible to handle** , if any alert by default provided by apple we can't handle